# 14.04 Nvidia issues - black screen, freeze etc

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have some issues with nvidia drivers on ubuntu 14.04, switchable graphics (intel HD + nvidia GT 740M).

Currently installed (from xorg-edgers repository): `nvidia-352` (was recommended by ubuntu-drivers devices) + `nvidia-prime` + `nvidia-settings`.

Issues (appears only when nvidia is selected in prime, with intel no problems):

- Blackscreen on login screen (I can hear sound, if I run `startx` from ctrl-alt-f1 and then stop it, or suspend/standby my pc and turn it on again - display appears).
- when using touchpad it freezes every few minutes, and ctrl-alt-f1 then ctrl-alt-f7 unfreezes it. I saw bug report regarding this issue and it was marked as patched/fixed so not sure what the problem is.

Nvidia settings can show temp etc and seems like the driver has good communication with nvidia card.

I tried to `purge nvidia*`. I tried using different drivers (nvidia-331). Both cause the same issues.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with hybrid graphics (aka switchable, etc) and nVidia Optimus technology is that nVidia doesn't give support of Optimus to Linux.  Meaning, you will always have problems of black screen when trying to run your machine with nVidia video chip directly.

To avoid this problem, there is a project called Bumblebee, which runs as main video chip the intel video integrated chip, turns off the nvidia to save power, and when you need video acelerating you can use optirun command to activate the nvidia chip.

You can find help about Bumblebee in the Ubuntu Help page:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Hope that helps you solve your problem

Comment: Well. Bumblebee has it's own huge disadvantages. I still prefer to use "prime".